# Space between asterisk and function name

Tags: c, function, pointers

Is this:

```
int * my_function( int variable )
```

the same than this:

```
int *my_function( int variable )
```

I understand that the first option is a function that returns a pointer (without name) to an integer but the second is a function (without name) that returns a pointer called my_function that points to an integer.

Comment: For the record, the reason one usually puts the asterisk next to the name it affects is because it takes effect per name, rather than being a part of the type declaration. For instance, in the case of `int *a, b`, only `a` is a pointer, so writing this as `int* a, b` or `int * a, b` could more easily confuse this.

Comment: There's not really any "reason" for the spacing, it is just historical preference. You can rationalize any variety.

Comment: Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are the same. In both cases, the function my_function returns pointer to ineteger

Answer (score 4):

The space is irrelevant. The type of the function is the same in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

```
 int * my_function( int variable );//fun my_function returns pointer to integer

 int *my_function( int variable );//here also fun my_function returns pointer to integer
```

for Function returning pointer second  declaration is generic way..syntax is

```
 type   *func (type1, type2,...);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remeber well, the debate was over whether the '*' is a part of the type or is only a modifier.
So char * cptr would mean that cptr is variable of type 'pointer to character' and char *cptr is a variable of type character pointed to (or an alike syntactical hasseling).